# Subclasses and Inheritance in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, class, google-apps-script, inheritance, subclass

Anyone have any patterns for writing and subclassing objects in Google Apps Script?

I've tried defining subclasses with `ParentClass.call(this, args)`, and putting parent class methods both in the original definition of the parent and assigning them to `ParentClass.prototype`.  But while this code passes unit tests, it fails when used in Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 3):

it's about class extend ( but javascript doesn't have real 'class' ).you may use `Prototype.js` or `mootool.js` or do like this?

```
function Human () {
    this.init.apply ( this, arguments );
}
Human.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        var optns = arguments[0] || {};
        this.age = optns.age || 0;
        this.name = optns.name || "nameless";
    },
    getName : function () {
        return this.name;
    },
    getAge : function () {
        return this.age;
    }
}

function Man () {
    this.init.apply ( this, arguments );
}
Man.prototype = {
    init : function () {
        Human.prototype.init.apply (this, arguments);
        this.sex = "man";
    },
    getName : Human.prototype.getName,
    getAge : Human.prototype.getAge,
    getSex : function () {
        return this.sex;
    }
}
function Woman () {
    this.init.apply ( this, arguments );
}
Woman.prototype = {
    init : function () {
        Human.prototype.init.apply (this, arguments);
        this.sex = "woman";
    },
    getName : Human.prototype.getName,
    getAge : Human.prototype.getAge,
    getSex : Man.prototype.getSex
}

var human = new Human({age:60,name:"Tom Tomas"}),
    man1 = new Man({age:30,name:"Wood Tomas"}),
    woman1 = new Woman({age:19,name:"Mary Tomas"});

console.log( human.getName() );
console.log( man1.getName() );
console.log( woman1.getName() );

console.log( human.getAge() );
console.log( man1.getAge() );
console.log( woman1.getAge() );

console.log( human.getSex && human.getSex() );
console.log( man1.getSex() );
console.log( woman1.getSex() );
```

or you could use jQuery's $.extend to do this. wish can help !

Comment: I'm down with all that, but I can't bring jQuery into Google App script.  So Prototype is very unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

Error: `ReferenceError: <class> is not defined`

If your code is correct and it still doesn't work on the Google Script platform (getting exception above), try sorting the file. Yes, really, sort it.

But even after sorting, if it throws '`ReferenceError: <class> is not defined`' error, try ordering the file manually. Make sure that the undefined class file is evaluated first by renaming the file.

001_Animal.gs < undefined class
002_Rabbit.gs
003_Main.gs

More information about this issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12687907/6327676).

I had a script with no code error, and it didn't work. Also, used [@Valentin's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66242802/6327676), didn't work either. All I had to do was sort. After that, it worked.

[image: Screenshot-sorting]

I'm using the [@Valentin's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66242802/6327676) here.
[image: Screenshot-before]

[image: Screenshot-after]

Answer (score 1):

It now goes easier! Try this

```
function test_inheritance() {

  let animal = new Animal("My animal");
  animal.run(22)

  let rabbit = new Rabbit("White Rabbit");

  rabbit.run(5); // White Rabbit runs with speed 5.
  rabbit.hide(); // White Rabbit hides!
}


class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.speed = 0;
    this.name = name;
  }
  run(speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
    console.log(`${this.name} runs with speed ${this.speed}.`);
  }
  stop() {
    this.speed = 0;
    console.log(`${this.name} stands still.`);
  }
}


class Rabbit extends Animal {
  hide() {
    console.log(`${this.name} hides!`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going:

```
var ApiService = {

/**
 * @params  {string}   bloggerId   The ID of your Blog
 * @returns {array}                Posted entries
 */
  getPosts: function (blogID) {  
    var feed = sendRequest_(feedUrl+blogID +"/posts/default");
    return feed;
  }
};


/**
 * First ParentClass (top level parent)
 */
ApiService.parent = function (parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
};

var ParentClass = ApiService.parent.prototype;

/**
 *  Gets the title of a post
 *
 * @param   {object)  post  An XML post entry
 * @returns {string}        The title of the post
 */
ParentClass.getTitle = function () {
    return this.parent.getElement('title').getText();
};
```

You would use it like:

```
var firstTitle = ApiService.getPosts()[0].getTitle();
```

Comment: I don't think this makes sense.